# Routing Error No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have made a controller and get the following error message

> Routing Error No route matches [GET] "handm/index"
>
> (these are the headings of the error table)
>
> Routes  Routes match in priority from top to bottom  Helper HTTP Verb
>   Path Controller#Action Path / Url
>
> (this is the contents)  handm_index_path  GET  /handm/index(.:format) 
>   handm#index root_path  GET  /  handm#index Request Parameters:

could somebody explain what this error means please.  below is my routes file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/handm/index' 
  root :to => "handm#index"
end
```

Comment: Try doing `get '/handm/index' => "handm#index"` instead of `get '/handm/index'`

Comment: this didn't work.

Comment: can you give you controller file, along with its name

Comment: `class HandmController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end`

Comment: could you please explain the general format of the error messages too?  what is the helpful information to identify the actual error in the message. it looks like gibberish to me at the moment. thanks

Comment: `get '/handm/index' => "handm#index"` this should work, You might be having template errors, which can be simply resolved by adding a file `index.html.[erb,haml]` whatever templating you are using, inside ***%AppRoot%/app/view/handm/index.html.erb***

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/handm/index' => 'handm#index'
  root :to => "handm#index"
end
```

**handm_controller.rb**

```
class HandmController < ApplicationController 
  def index 
    ...
  end 
end
```

**views/handm/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>In index page</h1>
```

Start your server by command:

```
rails server
```

and hit url:

```
localhost:3000
```

or

```
localhost:3000/handm/index
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the specified route or path doesn't exist.  So, the solution is to change it to a valid path.  We can only guess at the paths supported by your Rails app, but `/handm#index` is plausible:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/handm/index' => 'handm#index'
  root :to => "handm#index"
end
```

Comment: I don't think I downvoted anything. if I did it was by mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do      
  get '/handm/index', to: 'handm#index'
  root :to => "handm#index"
end
```

Comment: this didn't work either. same error message. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

i already solved mine,

you dont need to put http://127.0.0.1:3000/index

just this http://127.0.0.1:3000/
since you tell rails to make you index as root.

but you will have get a problem regarding javascript, 
to sovle you need to edit your application.js

edit this line //= require_tree . to = require_tree .

hope this will help